# Specifying a partial path for os.path.join

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that creates a PDF and saves it in a subfoler of the folder where the script is saved. I have the following that saves the file to the subfolder:

```
outfilename = "Test" + ".pdf" #in real code there is a var that holds the name of the file
outfiledir = 'C:/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/dev/PARENTFOLDER/SUBFOLDER/' #parent folder is where the script is - subfolder is where the PDFs get saved to
outfilepath = os.path.join(outfiledir, outfilename)
```

Is there a way I can save the PDFs to the subfolder without having to specify the full path? Lets say I wanted yto make this script an exe that multiple computers could use, how would I display the path so that the PDFs are just saved in the subfoler?

Thanks!

Comment: I would typically have the script take an argument (either through command line or in a config file) to pass in the output directory.  Something like:

`python <myscript> -o /path/to/outdir`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it:

```
import os
dir_name = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/subdir'
path = os.path.join(dir_name, 'filename')
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the `os.path.abspath(__file__)` part does, please?

Comment: Sure, `__file__` is module attribute, that saved path to this module.